# ReactJS Unit Testing - TypeError: this.props.onChange is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

I am doing unit-testing on React Components with karma+jasmine involving Login. The tests always throws error

```
? LoginForm test > ValidatedInput test > should validate password
```

> **TypeError: this.props.onChange is not a function**

```
 at ValidatedInput.handleChangeValue (src/components/ValidatedInput.js:14:24)
 at node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:844:23
 at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/Transaction.js:143:20)
 at Object.batchedUpdates (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62:26)
 at Object.batchedUpdates (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactUpdates.js:97:27)
 at ReactShallowRenderer.unstable_batchedUpdates (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactShallowRenderer.js:130:25)
 at performBatchedUpdates (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:103:21)
 at node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:843:13
 at withSetStateAllowed (node_modules/enzyme/build/Utils.js:284:3)
 at ShallowWrapper.simulate (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:840:42)
 at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/login-test.js:93:37)
 at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:42:16)
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Following are my files:

> **LoginForm.js** renders the component

```
<ValidatedInput
    name={'userId'}
    type={'text'}
    title={'User ID'}
    value={this.state.userId}
    placeholder={'Enter User ID'}
    onChange={this.handleUserIdChange}
    onComponentMounted={this.handleRegisterFormFields}
    validations={/^[0-9]{5,10}$/}
    validationError={'This is not valid user Id'}
    isRequired={true}
/>
```

I have bind the **handleUserIdChange** in constructor and defined in the class body as

```
handleUserIdChange(value) {
    this.setState({ userId : value });
}
```

> **ValidatedInput.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ValidatedInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleChangeValue = this.handleChangeValue.bind(this);
        this.isValid = this.isValid.bind(this);
        this.validateInput = this.validateInput.bind(this);
    }

    /**********************************************/
    // referred function //
    handleChangeValue(e) {
        this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
        var isValidField = this.isValid(e.target);
    }
    /**********************************************/    
    isValid(input) {
        if (input.getAttribute('required') !== null && input.value === "") {
            input.classList.add('Error');
            input.nextSibling.textContent = this.props.validationError;
            return false;
        } else {
            input.classList.remove('Error');
            input.nextSibling.textContent =  '';
        }

        if(input.value !== "") {
            if(!this.validateInput(input.value)) {
                input.classList.add('Error');
                input.nextSibling.textContent = this.props.validationError;
                return false;
            } else {
                input.classList.remove('Error');
                input.nextSibling.textContent =  '';
            }
        }
            return true;
    }

    validateInput(value) {
        var regularExpressionToBeMatched = this.props.validations;
        return regularExpressionToBeMatched.test(value);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.onComponentMounted) {
            this.props.onComponentMounted(this);
        }
    }

    render () {
        console.log(this.props.onChange);
        return (
            <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-5 text-center">
                    <label htmlFor={this.props.name}>{this.props.title}</label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-5 text-center">
                    <input
                        className="form-input text-center"
                        type={this.props.type}
                        ref={this.props.name}
                        name={this.props.name}
                        value={this.props.value}
                        required={this.props.isRequired}
                        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                        onChange={this.handleChangeValue}
                    />
                    <span className='Error'></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ValidatedInput;
```

The following is the code of the test:

```
it('should validate userId', () => {
    const component = shallow( <ValidatedInput
            name={'userId'}
            type={'text'}
            title={'User Id'}
            value={'001251623'}
            placeholder={'Enter User Id'}
            validations={/^[0-9]{5,10}$/}
            validationError={'This is not valid user Id'}
            isRequired={true}
    />);
    const handleChangeValue = spyOn(component.instance(), 'handleChangeValue');
    component.find('input').simulate('change', {target: { value: '00125' } });
    // expect(component.state().value).equals("00125");
    expect(handleChangeValue.calledWith('00125'));
});
```

I have looked extensively in all resources. The app is working fine and **console.log(this.props.onChange)** in ValidatedInput says **bound handleUserIdChange**. Please suggest a work-around or change.
Thanks.

***EDIT 1***

> LoginForm.js

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userId : '',
            password : '',
            loginType : ['Customer', 'Payer', 'Super-User'],
            userLoggedInAs : ['Customer'],
            userType : '',
            FieldsRegister : [],
            serverMessage : '',
        }
        this.handleClearForm = this.handleClearForm.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmitForm = this.handleSubmitForm.bind(this);
        this.handleUserIdChange = this.handleUserIdChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
        this.handleUserTypeChangeSelect = this.handleUserTypeChangeSelect.bind(this);
        this.handleRegisterFormFields = this.handleRegisterFormFields.bind(this);
    }

    handleUserIdChange(value) {
        this.setState({ userId : value });
    }
...
```

***EDIT 2***

```
it('should validate userId', () => {
            const component = shallow( <ValidatedInput
                    name={'userId'}
                    type={'text'}
                    title={'User Id'}
                    value={'001251623'}
                    placeholder={'Enter User Id'}
                    validations={/^[0-9]{5,10}$/}
                    validationError={'This is not valid user Id'}
                    isRequired={true}
                    onChange={handleUserIdChange()}
            />);
            const handleChangeValue = spyOn(component.instance(), 'handleChangeValue');
            component.find('input').simulate('change', {target: { value: '00125' } });
            // expect(component.state().value).equals("00125");
            expect(handleChangeValue.calledWith('00125'));
        });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example the `<ValidateInput>` component has the `onChange` prop:

```
<ValidatedInput
    ...
    onChange={this.handleUserIdChange}
```

But inside your test it doesn't:

```
        const component = shallow( <ValidatedInput
                name={'userId'}
                type={'text'}
                title={'User Id'}
                value={'001251623'}
                placeholder={'Enter User Id'}
                validations={/^[0-9]{5,10}$/}
                validationError={'This is not valid user Id'}
                isRequired={true}
                ---> Missing the onChange={..} <---
        />);
```

Comment: This is in the definition of the class, not in the instance of the component. Regarding which function should go there - i'm not sure what you want to tests, but you can (at least) pass there an empty function...

Comment: I have just edited my question. I am passing a handle to change the values of userId in ValidatedInput. Could you suggest now?
The error still persists though.

Comment: You still didn't change **anything** in the code of your test. Your tests has `undefined` for `prop.onChange` so when your `handleChangeValue` function tried to run `this.props.onChange(e.target.value)` what you actually do is run `undefined(e.target.value)`, which is wrong.

Comment: I have updated the test. Does it seem appropriate now? What did you mean  by empty function ( as in () )?

Comment: what is handleUserIdChange? does it return a function?

Comment: Regarding empty function - you can have `onChange={() => {}}`

Comment: I did add handleUserIdChange in Edit 1. Please see it.

Comment: Your usage is wrong. You should have `this.onChange={handleUserIdChange}` and not `handleUserIdChange()` - you want a reference to the function, and not the result of calling the function.

Comment: And I don't understand how a function with `this.setState` can be related to your test file. It looks like a function that exists inside your component...

Comment: How do you propose to check whether the input field is working which I am checking by passing the props. BTW ( () => {} ) seems to be working. I shall also accept your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the purpose of your test... you should test the logic you are trying to do there :)

Comment: Could you suggest something for testing such input field. It would be of great help.

Comment: As said - I'm not sure what the test should do

Comment: There is an input field in ValidatedInput rendered by my LoginForm. I am passing props to check whether the input field really takes the value passed. The field also has validation. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Basically you want to make sure that the `onChange` callback was called when you changed the value of the field, so this is what you should test. I'm not sure how you test this specific thing in your test system.